# Python Print function issue

Tags: python, excel

Hell there,

I designed a python code using "scrapy" to scrawl a URL page in order to extract the text I need on the page so as to import the results on an excel file. However, I struggle with the last part of the code, the print function. I do not know how to properly use print so that it exports the results of "'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first()" (the text in the URL) in the excel file. Can someone help me? 
I would really appreciate

Viktor

```
import scrapy

class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "brickset_spider"
start_urls = ['https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1944505.0']

def parse(self, response):
    POST_SELECTOR = '.post'
    for brickset in response.css(POST_SELECTOR):

         NAME_SELECTOR = 'div'
         yield {
            'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
         }
         import sys
         orig_stdout = sys.stdout
         f = open('Scrappingtest1.xls', 'a')
         sys.stdout = f
         print(yield)


    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    f.close()
```

Comment: Pass the file you want to write to as the `file` argument: `with open("...", 'a') as fh: print("hi", file=fh)`.

Comment: Sorry I do not really understand your proposal. In fact, within the command prompt, the 'name' returns the text within the URL. I just want this output to be transfered into an excel sheet. Thanks!

Comment: What is `print(yield)` supposed to do? Why do you have an `import` statement inside a function, and inside a loop?